# Include model relation with render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

Strange behavior:

This works in views (A):

```
<%= Contract.first.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.url %>
#=> Shows default image url
```

This does not in views (B):

```
<%= contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.url %>
```

> undefined method `receipt' for nil:NilClass

B is inside a partial and it's rendered as:

```
<% @contract.each do |contract|
 <%= render partial: 'expense_modal', locals: { contract: contract } %>
<% end %>
```

Guess I need not to confirm any relation as **A** works just fine. Is there an issue with **B**? Im using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Doing `Contract.first.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).inspect` I get what's expected but not so with `contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.inspect`

Edit

I have restarted server many time. Here are images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**views/expenses/_expense_model.html.erb:**

```
<%= contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.url %>
```

**views/expenses/show.html.erb:**

```
<% @contract.each do |contract|
 <%= render partial: 'expense_modal', locals: { contract: contract } %>
<% end %>
```

**Solution:**

Based on [Andrey Deineko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772830/andrey-deineko) comments I needed to add an if statement in the `expense_modal` view:

```
<% expense_obj = contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: contract.id) %>
<% if expense_obj %>
  <% receipt_url = expense_obj.receipt.url %>
<% else %>
  <% receipt_url = "/assets/receipt/missing-receipt.jpg" %>
<% end %>
```

Then:

```
<%= image_tag(receipt_url) %>
```

Comment: can you 100% guarantee, that `contract == Contract.first`?

Comment: Yes. `contract.inspect` = true. `contract.id.inspect = true`

Comment: no, please show me that `Contract.first.id == contract.id` => `true` (which i bet is `false`

Comment: `Contract.first.id` = `1` and same for `contract.id`. Do I need to show a screen shot?

Comment: this is impossible - see, what you're doing should be equal to `contract = Contract.first; contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.url` - if you run it in console it will work.

Comment: Let me add some screen shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might (and 99% it is) happen simply because

```
contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1)
```

returns `nil`, since there is no such `expense` object related with *this* *particular* `contract` object.

You are stating, that the following does not work, which is close to impossible :)

```
contract = Contract.first
contract.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.url # no way to not work
```

Comment: @Sylar your edit is fine and makes total sense. What I am trying to say, is that `@contract` contain some objects, that do not have corresponding `expenses` objects for specified criteria..

Comment: @Sylar You're doing `@contract.each` - just check, for example `@contract.map { |contract| expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1) }` - I bet you will get an array containing at least one `nil` value

Comment: Ok. This works `Contract.first.expenses.find_by(contract_id: 1).receipt.url` but this does not: `Contract.first.expenses.find_by(contract_id: contract.id).receipt.url` What's wrong with `contract.id`? Having `contract.id` alone I see `1`

Comment: @Sylar did you check the contents of  `@contract` variable? Run what I suggested in my previous comment and you'll see.

Comment: Good lord! I see you're right! Because there is a loop, one with an expense model and the other has none! So stupid of me! I deserve that downvote lol. Thanks for a second eye!

Comment: @Sylar no probs :) always debug step by step, it is the best you can do in such cases :)